# Strange artifacts when using git archive

Tags: git, git-archive

I'm currently trying to retrieve a single file from a GitLab Repo with the following command (I'm on Windows):

```
git archive --remote=git@git.myrepo.de:path/to/repo.git HEAD dir1/dir2/MyFile.xml > MyFile.xml
```

Essentially it works, but there are some strange artifacts in front and after the actual content of the file. This is how the command prompt shows them:

[image]

The XML version tag at the bottom of the image is the start of the actual file content. Does anyone have an idea how to get rid of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git archive` [creates tar archives](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive#Documentation/git-archive.txt---formatltfmtgt) even for 1 file. And that's exactly what you see at the screen — a content of a tar archive. Perhaps you ran the command without redirection or tried to cat `MyFile.xml` which is not an XML but a tar file.

To clear the screen run `clear`. To extract files from the archive use [`tar`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tar):

```
git archive --remote=git@git.myrepo.de:path/to/repo.git HEAD dir1/dir2/MyFile.xml | tar xvf -
```

Comment: Also since you're specifically downloading from a gitlab repo, [there's an API to get the raw file contents straight from gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#get-raw-file-from-repository), it's not necessary to go through the `git archive` dance if you don't want to support arbitrary git repositories.